# Python: find in BeautifulSoup works correctly on one windows machine and not correct on another

Tags: python, python-2.7, find, beautifulsoup, attributeerror

I have this simple code in Python 2.7 running on Windows 7 machines:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

def main():
    html_parser = HTMLParser()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen("http://www.amazon.com/gp/bestsellers/").read())

    categories = []

    for category_li in soup.find(attrs={'id':'zg_browseRoot'}).find('ul').findAll('li'):
        category = {}
        category['name'] = html_parser.unescape(category_li.a.string)
        category['url'] = category_li.a['href']

        categories.append(category)
```

When I run it on one machine it works fine and when I run it on another machine I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../tmp.py", line 10, in <module>
    for category_li in soup.find(attrs={'id':'zg_browseRoot'}).find('ul').findAll('li'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Can anyone help me to find out why? Both machines have Python 2.7 installed.
I really appreciate any help.

Comment: `soup.find(attrs={'id':'zg_browseRoot'})` is not returning anything on my machine

Comment: Are you using Python 2.7, and Windows 7? For me it is returning something on one machine and nothing on another.

Comment: Yes I am using Python 2.7

Comment: What parsers are installed?

Comment: I do not know, what do I need to install to get it working? Sorry I am only a beginner.

Comment: What is the value of `urlopen("http://www.amazon.com/gp/bestsellers/").read()` on each machine? Do they both contain `zg_browseRoot`?

Comment: I checked the above code on the second machine again and it works fine! But my first machine gives error.

Comment: run `from bs4.diagnose import diagnose;data = ....read();diagnose(data)`, it will tell you what parsers are available and any differences in how they parse the html

Comment: Sorry, the second line: 'data = ...read()' will this be `urlopen("http://www.amazon.com/gp/bestsellers/").read()` ?

Comment: Yes, exactly  the html.

Comment: Also make sure you are using the same version of bs4, you should update if you have a old version.

Comment: Ok I ran what you suggested and it returns a large number of lines starting with: `Diagnostic running on Beautiful Soup 4.3.2
Python version 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
I noticed that html5lib is not installed. Installing it may help.
Found lxml version 3.4.4.0

Trying to parse your markup with html.parser
Here's what html.parser did with the markup:
<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: Does this point that I need to install html5lib?

Comment: So you have lxml on both? Also what does `import bs4;bs4.__version__` output on both machines?

Comment: Both return" '4.3.2'

Comment: How can I check if I have lxml?

Comment: The diagnose code tells you what parsers are available. Do you get the same html back on the diagnose test on both machines?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Ok I ran the `diagnose` on both. On the one that gives error it says it Found lxml. On the one that works correctly it says it could not find lxml.

Comment: Ok so try `BeautifulSoup(urlopen("http://www.amazon.com/gp/bestsellers/").read(),"html.parser")`

Comment: On machine that does have lxml but gives attrebuteerror?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I get an error: `soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen("http://www.amazon.com/gp/bestsellers/").read(),"html.par‌​ser")
Unsupported characters in input`

Comment: Yes, whichever one that does not work

Comment: I get the error mentioned in previous comment

Comment: You must have a typo

Comment: `BeautifulSoup(urlopen("http://www.amazon.com/gp/bestsellers/").read(),"html.parser")`

Comment: Copied your line and pasted and get the same error: `Unsupported characters in input`

Comment: just type `"html.parser"` after .read

Comment: Wooow looks like it is working now :-)

Comment: Can you put this in an answer so I can accept it and explain what happened? You are a great programmer. Thanks so much.

Comment: @TJ1, no worries, i will add an answer in a bit and explain the differences, interestingly the code works for me with both but you have a slightly more updated version of lxml installed so that might be the difference

Comment: @PadraicCunningham thanks so much for spending your valuable time on this, I really appreciate it and I hope it helps someone else with similar problem, you are a great coder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The different output between running the code on the two different machines was the parser being used to parse the html. On the machine that did not work lxml was installed so bs4 was using that, on the machine that did work you were using `html.parser` which we found out using the diagnose code.

Running the diagnose code shows the available parsers on the system and how they parse the html:

```
from bs4.diagnose import diagnose
data = urlopen("http://www.amazon.com/gp/bestsellers/").read()
diagnose(data)
```

So changing the code on the system that had `lxml` installed to:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen("http://www.amazon.com/gp/bestsellers/").read(),"html.par‌​ser")
```

changing the parser to `html.par‌​ser`did the trick.

Interestingly I could run the code with either parser on ubuntu using the same version of  bs4 `4.3.2`, the only difference being my `lxml` version was slightly older `3.4.1.0 vs 3.4.4.0`.